# How to add an artboard preset in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

How do I add artboard presets in Illustrator CC 2014? I believe I've done it before, as I have some custom devices listed there currently. Google was not helpful.

I think it is in an Application Support folder somewhere.

[image: Illustrator Artboard Presets Dropdown]

Comment: If you're on a Mac:
Save a document to the New Document Profiles folder under Users > Library > Application Support > Adobe > [your current version of Illustrator].

Answer (score 1):

I have looked for this option in the past, with no solution. The closest/easiest workarounds I could come up with were these:

1) Create a document at the size you need, then Save As Template.

2) Create a new document, then create a new rectangle at the size you need. Open the Artboards palette, and under the flyout menu (top right in that palette), choose "Convert to Artboards". Then in that same palette, delete the original artboard.

Good luck!

Comment: If you're on a Mac:
Save a document to the New Document Profiles folder under Users > Library > Application Support > Adobe > [your current version of Illustrator].